# Setting IDs per PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a PowerShell script, which fills the `Usrid` custom attribute with `EMP$ID` value. `$ID` is a continuous number, which is normally stored in a text file and continuously written after setting the ID and set it one up. First I get with `Get-ADUser` all users without a ID, then will set the ID into `Usrid` attribute.

My problem is: I want to check if the ID or value exists.

- If ID exists → `$ID++`
- else → set ID from File and write it to file again

The `if` part in the script looks like this:

```
# I'm calling the content or the last ID
$lastid = Get-Content "C:\startid.txt"

# Convert the content into a decimal string
$Usrid = [System.Decimal]::Parse($lastid)

# Find out all userProxyFull Object without an ID 
Get-ADObject -Filter {(objectClass -eq "userProxyFull") -and (-not(Userid -like "*"))} -Searchbase "DC=MY,DC=SEARCHBASE" -Searchscope subtree -Server myIP | 
    ForEach-Object {
        # Then the problem part here, see description above
        if ({Usrid -eq "EMP$ID"}) {
            $ID++
            Set-ADObject $_ -Partition "DC=my,DC=partition" -Add @{Usrid="EMP$ID"}
        } else {
            Set-ADObject $_ -Partition "DC=my,DC=partition" -Add @{Usrid="EMP$ID"}
        } 
    }
```

But the script doesn't check. Or how can I check the highest ID and set the highest ID into `Usrid` attribute?

Comment: `{Usrid -eq "EMP$ID"}` -> `$_.Usrid -eq "EMP$ID"`. For further help you need to provide more context on your code, the objects you're processing, and how do you want their attribute change. What if `$ID` has a value of 3 while the attribute is `EMP13`, `EMP1`, `EMP3`, `EMP03`, ...?

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What do you want to happen when `Usrid` is empty? What do you want to happen when `Usrid` has a value with a higher ID? Lower ID? Should it be left untouched? Should all objects have the same `Usrid` value after the operation?

Comment: The importet text file contains a ID f.ex. **26**.  When `Usrid` is empty, it should check, if **26** is in use, if not, then write it as value into `Usrid`, when use check the next possible (27) value and write it as value. I cut the EMP per batch script left, so my text file contains only the highest existing decimal string 26 and not the EMP (highest Usrid in our AD). I need EMP only during filling the IDs. We haven't thought about your last question yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Usrid` needs to be unique you need to compare your input value against the already existing attribute values.

```
$existing = @{}
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(UserId=*)' -Property Usrid | ForEach-Object {
    $existing[$_.Usrid] = $true
}

while ($existing.ContainsKey("EMP$ID") {
    $ID++
}
```

At this point you have a `$ID` where none of the existing accounts has a `Usrid` attribute with the value `EMP$ID`. Then you can go ahead and assign the attribute on all account objects where it doesn't have a value yet while incrementing `$ID` after each assignment:

```
Get-ADObject ... | ForEach {
    Set-ADObject $_ -Partition "DC=my,DC=partition" -Add @{Usrid="EMP$ID"}
    $ID++
}
```

Note, however, that the above is assuming that there are no gaps in your numbering (i.e. you don't have a situation where you have attribute values ..., `EMP25`, `EMP26`, `EMP28`, ...). If that assumption doesn't apply you're better off determining the next available ID by getting the highest already assigned ID and incrementing that value by 1:

```
$ID = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(Userid=*)' -Property Usrid |
      ForEach-Object { [int]($_.Usrid -replace '^EMP') } |
      Sort-Object |
      Select-Object -Last 1
$ID++
```